# No Android status bar with relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app with Android Studio 2.2.3 and I'm facing a problem I did not find before: if I add an Activity from a template such as **Basic Activity**, the newly created activity will let the device status bar display

[image]

If I add instead an activity from the **Empty Activity** template, no status bar shows up any more.

Reading through the layout files, I see that the **Basic activity** uses a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` whereas the **Empty Activity** uses a `RelativeLayout`. I cannot find any other differences, neither in the manifest. I programmed some apps with Eclipse some time ago and the status bar was there, even with the RelativeLayout, as far as I remember.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance, regards

**Edit:**

> Status bar does not relate with layout. It is about the theme defined in the styles.xml. Can you check which theme is applied your activity?

Thanks steve for your suggestion: the behavior is due to

[image: Thems - no actionbar]

Yet another question: keeping this no-actionbar theme, why is my textbox not aligned with the top of the screen, like this:

[image]

My activity layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.pgsoftware.firebasepublisher.Main4Activity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test string"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and with the *Layout inspector* I get the following UI structure:

[image]

The LinearLayout at the top has a 72dp top-padding which I can't find digging into the themes: any suggestion?

Thanks in advance, regards

Comment: You want status bar or you dont want status bar, what is your question?

Comment: Status bar  does not relate with layout. It is about the theme defined in the styles.xml. Can you check which theme is applied your activity?

Comment: @user1737538 **Where is your question honey?** What do you want to achieve ? or clear what suggestion you are asking for?

Comment: I do want the status bar and at the time of Eclipse I think it was the default behavior. Maybe default themes were different. What is strange is that Basic and Blank activity have different behavior, but the theme is the same. I will read through the theme as suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `android:appTheme="@style/AppTheme"` option in the manifest file . Check the theme option in *res>style.xml* file . Copy the stylesheet and paste in comment to see.

Comment: If you dont have enough reputation  to comment **Do not post your comments as answers**